# Java development on Windows 8 tablet

Tags: java, windows, tablet

Thinking about getting a Windows 8 Tablet so I can do dev when I'm not at home. How is the Windows tablet for dev? Would appreciate some feedback.

Comment: will "good" count as an answer...jst kidding :) I know people who use Win8 Tablet. It depends on what app you are trying to write and who are your target users.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As long as you get the pro version it'll be great. The other version lacks the desktop and the ability to be "really useful". I've tried this with an android as well - even though they offer an IDE it's not the same. If you have the cash the Dell Convertible (folding laptop to tablet) is a great option to do everything you need.

Comment: Thanks. I have an XPS 15 laptop as my primary workstation and love it. The dell tablet looks tight. You've given me lots to think about.